# Mobilefirst can not store userid into worklight database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using adapter-based authenticators. `WL.Server.setActiveUser` was called on the adapter.

I user `WL.Logger.info` to print out the parameters which I send to `setActiveUser`. They are correct.

In WL console, DeviceId got updated ,but we can not saw the userid in the device table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwqbW.png)

we are using MFP 7.1 version.

---

We got below error in the log file.  not sure it is related to the issue.

> [9/5/16 23:09:48:567 EDT] 000000f4 GadgetAPIServ E com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet createAjaxRequestExceptionJSON FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.ibm.pushworks.server.entities.PushSubscription-com.ibm.pushworks.server.entities.PushSubscription-2] [project ]
>   [9/5/16 23:09:48:579 EDT] 000000f4 GadgetAPIServ E  createAjaxRequestExceptionJSON FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project ]Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.ibm.pushworks.server.entities.PushSubscription-com.ibm.pushworks.server.entities.PushSubscription-2], User Identity {wl_directUpdateRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule), SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, ServicesRealm=(name:xxx@cn.ibm.com, loginModule:StrongDummy), wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLRemoteDisableNullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=(name:xxx@cn.ibm.com, loginModule:StrongDummy), wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:qmd8e821mcil59j4tedagchnvi, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:D07571B0-2685-4F6F-9C42-37B616F52190, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:ea57e780-ce09-4bbd-aee5-5a1701388b72, loginModule:WeakDummy), wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:ea57e780-ce09-4bbd-aee5-5a1701388b72, loginModule:WeakDummy)}. [project ]

---

Answer (score 0):

It seems the security test defined in Authentication config file is not mentioned in Application Descriptor file . Please cross check security test in AuthenticatonConfig.xml and applicationDescription.xml 
please follow below link.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/